# How to get key value from multiple nested json in Java

Tags: java, json, nested

I am using Java for my application. I want to process the multi level nested json and form as a key value pair.

**Mapping format 1 is defined as Map<String, Object>:**

```
{
    "first_name": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "date_of_birth": {
        "type": "date"
    },
    "last_name": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "video": {
      "type": "nested", 
      "properties": {
        "id":    { "type": "integer"  },
        "title":     { "type": "string"   },
        "description":   { "type": "string"   }
      }
    },
    "address": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "work": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "home": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected result:**

```
{
    "first_name": "string"  ,
    "date_of_birth": "date",
    "last_name": "string",
    "video.id": "integer",
    "video.title": "string",
    "video.description": "string",
    "address.work": "string",
    "address.home": "string"
}
```

**Mapping format 2 is defined as Map<String, Object>:**

```
{
    "first_name": "string"
    "date_of_birth": "date"
    "last_name": "string"           
    "video": {
        "id": "integer",
        "title": "string",
        "description": string",
        "mpeg": {
            "format": "string",
            "name": "string"
        }
    },
    "address": {                
        "work": "string",               
        "home": "string"                
    }
}
```

**Expected result:**

```
{
    "first_name": "string",
    "date_of_birth": "date",
    "last_name": "string",
    "video.id": "integer",
    "video.title": "string",
    "video.description": "string",
    "video.description": "string",
    "video.mpeg.format": "string",
    "video.mpeg.name": "string",
    "address.work": "string",
    "address.home": "string"
}
```

How to get expected results for the above using Map in Java 11?

Answer (score 0):

The question states that the 'json' is received in the form `Map<String, Object>`. This raises an alarm bell: `Object` is the root of the Java class hierarchy and instances of type `Object` generally need to be cast to a class that they are an `instanceof` to be used. Without knowing more about the actual type of the map values it's not possible to provide advice on how to use them.

Ideally, you should use a json parser to convert your json into a structure you can query. There are several around.

Using https://github.com/google/gson as an example parser:

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement element = parser.parse(input);
```

To convert to your map I'd recommend a recursive algorithm to cope with the tree structure. In pseudo code it'd look something like:

```
addToMap(map, prefix, node)
     if node.key is 'type'
         put(prefix, node.value) in map
     else
         for each child node in node.value
             addToMap(map, prefix + "." + node.key, child)
```

Comment: Is there a way do using map itself instead of JsonParser?

Comment: @Galet I'll add a comment into the answer on that